# AD CS Certificate Enrollment Change Private Key

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, windows-server-2012

i setted up an cert autoenrollment with template for an user and the group. At the template i set the archivable flag.

My Problem now is, i would like to autoenroll an "refreshed" cert with new public key and private key (stored at AD CS) but keeping the old public key (so the cert) as long as requested.

In conclusion i need multiple autoenrolled certs of same template on request over many machines.

Could sombody help?

Thanks a lot.

(c# at least the request and readings of certs)